# Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem: proof by direct estimate rather than analytic majorization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, power-series, alternative-proof

I'm reading the section about analytic solutions in *Partial Differetial Equation* of Evans. In the book, the theorem of Cauchy–Kowalevski which states the local existence of analytic solutions is proved by **analytic majorization**. Below is the description of this proof in wikipedia.

> Both sides of the partial differential equation can be expanded as formal power series and give recurrence relations for the coefficients of the formal power series for f that uniquely determine the coefficients. The Taylor series coefficients of the Ai's and b are majorized in matrix and vector norm by a simple scalar rational analytic function. The corresponding scalar Cauchy problem involving this function instead of the Ai's and b has an explicit local analytic solution. The absolute values of its coefficients majorize the norms of those of the original problem; so the formal power series solution must converge where the scalar solution converges.

**I'm looking for a proof of this theorem by direct estimate rather than analytic majorization, which means we estimate the coefficients of the formal power series and deduce the convergence of the series directly.** I think by direct estimate we can understand this theorem deeper and derive more precise results. I have found no such proof on Internet, and I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a reference.